# Count length of value within a cell with full-width characters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I use this function to limit the length of value within cells:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var limit = 6;
  if(e.value.length > limit) {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.substring(0, limit) + "... out of limit.");
    // e.range.setNote("Remaining text was: \n....." + e.value.substring(limit));
  }
}
```

However, I want to count the length of full-width characters (like Chinese or Japanese characters) as 2 and half-width characters as 1. Is there anyway to do this?

Example:
length of "abcあいう" should equal to 9.

Comment: Just to note, there are also full-width versions of Latin characters ([example](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff21/index.htm)) - I assume those also need to be taken into account. (I added the `javascript` tag to get more views for this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this JavaScript version of PHP `mb-strwidth()` by [demouth](https://gist.github.com/demouth/3217440).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var limit = 6;
  if (strLen(e.value) > limit) {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.substring(0, limit) + "... out of limit.");
    // e.range.setNote("Remaining text was: \n....." + e.value.substring(limit));
  }
}

function strLen(str) {
  var l = str.length;
  var c = '';
  var length = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (0x0000 <= c && c <= 0x0019) {
      length += 0;
    } else if (0x0020 <= c && c <= 0x1FFF) {
      length += 1;
    } else if (0x2000 <= c && c <= 0xFF60) {
      length += 2;
    } else if (0xFF61 <= c && c <= 0xFF9F) {
      length += 1;
    } else if (0xFFA0 <= c) {
      length += 2;
    }
  }
  return length;
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
function strLen(str = "abcあいう") {
  var l = str.length;
  var c = '';
  var length = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (0x0000 <= c && c <= 0x0019) {
      length += 0;
    } else if (0x0020 <= c && c <= 0x1FFF) {
      length += 1;
    } else if (0x2000 <= c && c <= 0xFF60) {
      length += 2;
    } else if (0xFF61 <= c && c <= 0xFF9F) {
      length += 1;
    } else if (0xFFA0 <= c) {
      length += 2;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(length);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [HTML Unicode](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp)
- [mb_strwidth](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strwidth.php)

Comment: Consider this input string: `Āあ`. This should return `3`, but it returns`4`. There are many regular width characters with code points greater than 256, using `charCodeAt()` (and `codePointAt()`).

Comment: The length part works well as expected. Thank you! However, it seems like `e.value.substring` does not work for full-width characters -- it still counts full-width character as 1 character. Probably the `substring` function needs to be re-written. I will try to re-write `substring` using your `strLen()` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Just a supplement to [Nikko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68413825/12427876).

Since `e.value.substring` does not work properly for full-width characters, I wrote a new substring function for strings containing full-width characters based on `strLen()`.

```
function substringFullWidth(str, limit) {
  var l = str.length;
  var c = '';
  var res = '';
  var length = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (0x0000 <= c && c <= 0x0019) {
      // length 0
      // do nothing
    } else if (0x0020 <= c && c <= 0x1FFF) {
      // length 1
      length = length + 1;
    } else if (0x2000 <= c && c <= 0xFF60) {
      // length 2
      length = length + 2;
    } else if (0xFF61 <= c && c <= 0xFF9F) {
      // length 1
      length = length + 1;
    } else if (0xFFA0 <= c) {
      // length 2
      length = length + 2;
    }
    if (length <= limit) {
      res += str.charAt(i);
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```